# AsyncStorage in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm learning to program in React-Native and I need to use Asyncstorage to check if a user is logged in or not. I use router-flux for the actions in the App.

I have a question about the use of AsyncStorage.

So Let's start! I have 3 pages for the user. An Authentication Page, an Login Page, and a HomePage.

The first page is Authentication. I have created a white page between the Login and the signup in which I do control with the AsyncStorage.

So I have Authentication -> White Page -> Login or HomepageUser.

Now the problem is that with this process when I am in the login page, and I go back (with the bottom in the app or with the bottom in the phone) I return in the white page.

```
    class Starting extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    User.getUserLoggedIn()
      .then(UserLoggedIn => {
        if (UserLoggedIn !== null) {
          global.utente = new Utente(JSON.parse(dataUtenteLoggato));
          Actions.homepageutente();
        } else {
          Actions.login();
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={style.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#64c7c0" />
       </View>
```

In **User**

```
 static async getUserLoggedIn() {
    try {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem("@UserLoggedIn");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

How can I avoid this?
There is an alternative way I can implement if not the use of a blank page?
Thank you

Comment: This code alone cannot reproduce your problem. Show me the whole code.

Comment: @hongdevelop The problem is at theory level, the code is only about the method that I use to do the AsyncStorage

Comment: Which navigator are you using?? react navigation??

Comment: @BanidAzin router-flux